# Is this the correct way to use sp_executesql in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have this huge stored procedure where I am building a sql statement.  At the end, I create a parameter list like this:

DOES @paramList need and N in front of it??

```
SELECT @paramList = '@param1 nvarchar(300),
              @param2 nvarchar(10),
          @param3 nvarchar(10),
          @param4 nvarchar(100),
          @param5 nvarchar(1000),
          @param6 nvarchar(1000),
          @param7 nvarchar(200),
          @param8 nvarchar(2000)’
```

I am then calling sp_executesql like this:

```
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @paramList,
     @param1,@param2,@param3,@param4,
             @param5,@param6,@param7,@param8
```

where @sql is the statement, paramList is my parameter list and all the other variables are the parameters I declared at the top of the stored procedure.  Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: does it run? if so, you got it! if not give the error message here.

Comment: Looks like you've got a curly quote on the end of the paramList, but that could just be an artifact of whatever tool you're using.

Comment: It runs.  Yeah that is supposed to be a single qoute, but it came out looking strange.  I was using word to format.  The reason I asked if it were correct is because when I run a trace, I don't see it saying sp_executesql, it just says EXEC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the string does not use characters outside the database collation, the N'' notation is not required.

You did not state the declaration of @paramList. N'' would only be useful if it is declared NVARCHAR.

SQL server automatically takes care of conversion between VARCHAR and NVARCHAR values (again with regard to the db collation).

So, in your case, the solution works. The "correct" way would be to use NVARCHAR and N'', but in this case is not required.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's the right way. You can pass the `'@param1 nvarchar(300), ..., @param8 nvarchar(2000)'` dirrectly to `sp_executesql`, no need to pass it through @paramList. Also, the second argument to `sp_executesql` is an unicode type, so you probably do some extra ascii-to-unicode conversations. You could do straight:

```
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, 
     N'@param1 nvarchar(300),...,@param8 nvarchar(2000)', 
     @param1,...,@param8;
```

Is it better to keep the parameter list declaration in the call itself, because is so tightly coupled with the actual parameters passed.

Comment: I passed it as @paramList because that's how microsoft had an example set up.

Comment: Fair enough. But in the MSDN example the `@ParmDefinition` is `N'...'`, not `'...'` (ie. is unicode).

Comment: If i do pass @paramList, do I have to put N' in front of @paramList like so,  @paramList = N'@param1 nvarchar(100),@param2 nvarchar(50)'

Comment: The list has to be unicode. If you use an ascii variable or construct an ascii literal, an extra conversion occurs that can be avoided. Is not critical, just a nuance.

Comment: So if I use an ascii datatype in my parameter list, I have to convert it to unicode, but if I use unicode types, I do not, correct?